# Админка MODX показывает пустой экран

Tags: modx

Столкнулся с проблемой на сайте, сделанном на MODX. Пытаюсь зайти в админ-панель, но переход упорно показывает белый экран.

Логи показывают:

[2024-01-29 10:52:13] (ERROR @ /home/a0510260/domains/biostimul-altay.ru/core/xpdo/xpdo.class.php : 644) Could not load class: msPromoCode from mspromocode.

[2024-01-29 10:52:13] (ERROR @ /home/a0510260/domains/biostimul-altay.ru/core/xpdo/xpdo.class.php : 1247) Problem getting service mspromocode, instance of class msPromoCode, from path /home/a0510260/domains/biostimul-altay.ru/core/components/mspromocode/model/mspromocode/

Как я понимаю, mspromocode это плагин, сниппет, ну что-то в этом духе для MODX, я нашел файлы, но там строка отвечает как раз за вывод ошибки

```
$this->log(xPDO::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "Could not load class: {$classname} from {$fqn}.");

$this->log(xPDO::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "Problem getting service {$name}, instance of class {$class}, from path {$path}");
```

Что пытался сделать:

1. Почистил папку кэша - не помогло
2. Переходил не просто в /manager, а /manager/?a=system/settings - не помогло

Многие решения в интернете эти ошибки убирают через админку, а я как раз  в админку не могу попасть. Надеюсь на Вашу помощь, может кто сталкивался.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте переустановить этот пакет через менеджер пакетов. Согласно логу штатно пакет не загружается. Возможно что-то сломалось ранее в процессе обновлений/переносов. Если версия MODX старовата до кучи будет полезно обновить и ее.